# Significant performance improvement in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to find some papers on the web which would talk about significant improvements in Java with regards to improvements since 2002, but I cannot find anything. Could someone point me into right place, but please don't say go to sun website. I've been there and I really couldn't find any material which would discuss those improvements with relation to earlier versions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134986/how-can-the-what-stack-overflow-is-not-post-be-improved

Comment: @Leon Cullens: that's a ridiculously false statement. That it gets upvoted proves only that some people love confirming their prejudices far too much.

Comment: You can refer Wikipedia. It shows what are all the improvements by versions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Comment: @LeonCullens - that is simply not true. [An example of an improvement in Java 6 - from the Sun web page](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/6_performance.html#2.4.2), or [G1 collector in Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/g1-intro-jsp-135488.html)

Comment: @those_who_closed are you guys serious? How this can be non-constructive? Look how many different opinions are here? Surely knowing something is constructive, isn't it? Guys, really think before you act, it will be good for you.

Answer (score 5):

The [Java SE 6 performance white paper](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/6_performance.html) has a very detailed list of performance improvements that were introduced in Java 6, including benchmarks.

For Java 7, there is a [much shorter document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html), which doesn't have any benchmarks.

If these aren't what you're looking for, you should describe your requirements better.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia page [Java version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) has references to performance improvements and is a good starting point